# how will this linq query execute

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

I have a function to retrive the user detail

I have encryped few fields. I want to know how the LINQ will execute the actual sql query

```
public User GetUserByEmail(string email)
{
      return _db.Users.Where(x => x.LastName.Decrypt() == "Patel").ToList();
}
```

**x.LastName.Decrypt()** will it fetch all records from sql and perform decrypt on each field in the code side ?

What if i use

```
public User GetUserByEmail(string email)
{
      return _db.Users.Where(x => x.LastName == "Patel".Encrypt()).ToList();
}
```

which one is better

Comment: Please provide `Decrypt` definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good chances are that your first query isn't going to work at all, unless you force bringing the data into the memory by calling `AsEnumerable()`, `ToList`, or `ToArray`, because EF provider does not know how to translate your `Encrypt` function to SQL.

The second query, on the other hand, should work fine, because it's a string-to-string comparison.

In addition, the second way of querying lets you implement a potentially more secure scheme when "encrypting" a string cannot be reversed with a `Decrypt`, e.g. when you store a message digest.

Comment: you are right @dasblinkenlight, the first query will result in a runtime error

Answer (score 0):

Calling `.Decrypt()` in the `Where` function will decrypt the `LastName` on each & every row.  You're better off with the .Encrypt() method you displayed, which will call 'Encrypt` once and compare each LastName to the encrypted string for "Pate1".